# How can I make a C# "using" alias public to avoid "inconsistent accessibility" errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, types, properties

I have a C# class that defines a few aliases with the *using* keyword for some public properties.  This leads to "inconsistent accessibility" compiler errors since apparently the types defined by the aliases are not public.  How can I make the types defined by the aliases public too so the error goes away?

```
// Alias defined at the top of the source file just below the other "using"
//  "using" statements that bring in the needed modules.
using TDynamicStringArray = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;

// Public property defined with the type alias.
public TDynamicStringArray Strs
{
    ...
}
```

Here is the Error received from the compiler:

```
Error   2   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'TDynamicStringArray' is less accessible than property 'Strs'
```

I tried putting *public* in front of *using* but that doesn't work.  I looked at several other SO threads on the topic of "inconsistent accessibility" but did not see any that dealt with type aliases created with the *using* keyword.

The reason I am using the alias is because I am converting some old code from another language, and it simplifies the conversion process.  Otherwise I would just use the underlying type without the alias.

Comment: Out of interest, I may be missing something but why would you use `TDynamicStringArray` when you could `List<string>` is just as easy to write and read?

Comment: I agree with @AshBurlaczenko, Even if it's defined using the fully qualified name it seems silly to use an alias

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - As I said in my post, I am converting old code and the way that type is intertwined in the old code makes it easier to use the alias.

Comment: This compiles in my VS2010, could you explain better the context of the error or provide some more code?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change type's accessibility through any other mechanism but changing type itself.

If you can't modify source for the type your only option is to wrap it in your custom public type.

Comment: I have the source as you can see from my post.  Can you give an example of what you are saying as it applies to my example?  Otherwise I don't know what are suggesting.

Comment: @RobertOschler, I'm sorry - I was answering question in title. My understanding of the part of the code that you have not posted is you have some other type with the same (non-aliased) name that have lower accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

Aliases don't define types; they just refer to an existing type. There is no accessiblity associated with an alias.

In your example, `List<string>` is public, and you shouldn't get that error message. My guess is that you have a non-public `TDynamicStringArray` class somewhere, and the alias doesn't get used at all.